# css not being applied to document.write text

Tags: javascript, css, document.write

I'm writing text to a page using document.write for a Chrome extension, but the associated custom CSS isn't applied:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TITLE GOES HERE</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/popup.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        ...
        function showFolder(folder) {
            console.debug('FOLDER: '+folder.title);
            document.write('<p>'+folder.title+'<br></p>');
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The CSS is simple, just for debugging:

```
p {
color: red;
}
```

I can get it to work if I put the stylesheet link inside the function showFolder, but that can't be the proper way to do it. I'm learning jscript/CSS on the fly, so the answer is probably something remedial. Is the problem in the jscript, the CSS or both?

Comment: Where are you calling `showFolder`? Do you have another style sheet that could conflict and override the style? I tested what you have here and it works fine in Google Chrome if you call `showFolder` after the function declaration instead of where you have `...`

Comment: showFolder is called from inside another function (...), which reads the folders inside Chrome bookmarks (basically 'read bookmark tree'-> 'if item is a folder, display the folder's name via showFolder). Just for kicks I moved the showFolder declaration before the ... function, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use innerHTML.

```
<div id="towrite"></div>
```

then you can write in it like this:

```
div=document.getElementById('towrite');
div.innerHTML = '<p>'+folder.title+'<br></p>';
```

Comment: Gonna give this a go now. Will report back. Thanks!

Comment: Combined with document.createElement (I needed to create several divs dynamically), this worked great. Thanks again.

Comment: There's a missed quotation mark in this answer, it should be
`<div id="towrite"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

If you run your document.write() before the page finishes loading (perhaps calling your showFolder call directly from a script on the page), then the text will be written into the document as you might expect.

However, if you call document.write after the page loads, as in an event handler, you will be writing an entirely new page. This is usually not what you want.

Instead, follow Zoltan's advice and set the innerHTML property of an empty div.

Comment: Thanks--it really helps to know the 'why' and not just the 'what'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not javascript expert... I mainly use jQuery.. but try this, kind of makes sense:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

TITLE GOES HERE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ...
    function showFolder(folder) {
        console.debug('FOLDER: '+folder.title);
        document.write('<p>'+folder.title+'<br></p>');
    }
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/popup.css" type="text/css" />
```

EDIT:

So the above didn't work, but I just thought about another solution. When are you actually calling the function? Try to put it in `<body onLoad="functionnamehere()">`

No idea if that works, but give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the reply--Moving the stylesheet link out of the head and after the script didn't work.

Comment: I discovered that a huge part of the problem was that every time document.write was called it wiped out everything in the HEAD (Apparently it basically resets the page), including the LINK tag. Zoltan's solution above got me on the right track.