# Want to print a div section with external style sheet

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to print a div section.

All of the class I have used within the div and other tags which are the child of the main div (printable div) are defined in an external style sheet.

How do I print the div same as it's displayed on the web page?

my code is

```
function printContent(el){
// el has the id of div to print //
var printcontent = '<html><head><link href="http://website-domain/css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></head>' + document.getElementById(el).innerHTML+'</html>';
console.log(printcontent);
document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
window.print();
```

}

Comment: Show us some code and what you've already tried.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question. Show us some code, explain your problem better & show us what you've tried so far. We're here to help you with your code, but we're not here to write code for you. Also, we can't help you if you don't provide more information, because at the moment its completly unclear what you're asking. Please edit your question, otherwise it will be downvoted quite fast.

Comment: I have edited my post by paste my code

Answer (score 0):

```
function PrintElem(elem) {
  var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');

  mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title + '</title>');

  mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
  mywindow.document.write('<h1>' + document.title + '</h1>');
  mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML);
  mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

  mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
  mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

  mywindow.print();
  mywindow.close();

  return true;

}
```

pass the reference of element which you want to print as elem parameater.

Comment: Thanx for quick response. I use this code but it can't load my external stylesheet .....   that's why I get a simple layout of print content, not get a well designed content

Comment: Dinemicully Creat those CSS in same function using javascript or jquery.

Comment: I did this but can't load css                                                                                      mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title + '</title>'<link href="http://website-url/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">);

Comment: [This Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789695/css-not-being-applied-to-document-write-text) might help you.

Comment: I checked given link by RRajni but still facing same issue