# css doesn't work when using document.write()

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the materialize css in my html, and everything seems to be styled correctly except for the document.write() code. What do I need to do so that the document.write() code also gets styled.

Here is my html:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>STL Info</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="container">
        <h1>STL Info</h1>
        <div class="file-field input-field">
          <div class="btn waves-effect waves-light">
            <span>STL File</span>
            <input type="file" onchange="uploadFile(this)">
          </div>
          <div class="file-path-wrapper">
            <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            function uploadFile(fileInput) {
                var files = fileInput.files;
                var fileName = files[0].name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");;
                document.write('<h1>STL Info</h1>') //this isnt styled
                document.write('Volume: '+volume(fileName+'.stl')); // or this
                document.write('<br>')// or this
                document.write('Surface Area: '+surfaceArea(fileName+'.stl'));// or this
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789695/css-not-being-applied-to-document-write-text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `document.write()` after page load is finished, you will write a new page (you "reset" your current page).

Try `innerHTML` instead, by "overwriting" the HTML inside of your `path-file-wrapper` div:

```
function uploadFile(fileInput) {
  var files = fileInput.files;
  var fileName = files[0].name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
  var divToWrite = document.getElementsByClassName('file-path-wrapper')[0];
  divToWrite.innerHTML = "Volume: " + volume(fileName + '.stl') + "<br>Surface Area: " +surfaceArea(fileName + '.stl');
}
```